# Get product attribute value from custom group

Tags: attributes

I've added a new attribute group "Floor Inventory" with three attributes whose attribute codes are flr00, flro1 and flr02.

I'm trying to get value of flr00 for product with id 2 in root Magento but it's returning NULL value.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
var_dump($_product->getData('flr00'));
exit();
```

Comment: Do you have multiple storeviews? If so check values for this fields in all store views, maybe some of them overwrites the default one. Check if attribute is assign to attribute set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the attribute value, use this

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2); 
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('flr00')->getFrontend()->getValue($produc‌​t);
echo $attribute_value;
```

It seems impossible to get value without loading product model. If you take a look at file `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/Abstract.php` you'll see the method

```
public function getValue(Varien_Object $object)
{
    $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
    if (in_array($this->getConfigField('input'), array('select','boolean'))) {
        $valueOption = $this->getOption($value);
        if (!$valueOption) {
            $opt = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean();
            if ($options = $opt->getAllOptions()) {
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                        $valueOption = $option['label'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $value = $valueOption;
    }
    elseif ($this->getConfigField('input')=='multiselect') {
        $value = $this->getOption($value);
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = implode(', ', $value);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

As you can see this method requires loaded object to get data from it (3rd line).

Hope this helps

Comment: tried `var_dump(Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue(2, 'flr00', 1));`
but it returns `bool(false)`  while `$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
$value    = $_product->getData('flr00');
var_dump($value);` returns NULL.

Comment: `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(877);
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('gender')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);echo $attribute_value` This works for me.!

Comment: Check my updated ans

Comment: why you're passing `$product` again in `getValue($product); ` there?. It doesn't work either. Should var_dump($product) contain flroo attribute?

Comment: Check my edited answer. This wil answer your curiosity